# Moving row from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to StackOverflow, but have been working on this problem for some time, and am pretty stuck. Right now, my code takes 'Name' input from a textbox, and if the data in column A matches the name that was input, it copies data from the entire row in that sheet, copies it to another sheet, then deletes the data from the original sheet, and tells the user how many rows were moved. This code is listed below:

I have two problems. One, I need an error check where if the name that is typed into the textbox does not exist, it displays a messagebox with that message, and two, I need to allow for this code to do what it does, but from seperate workbooks. As in, copy the data from a sheet in one workbook, and move it to a sheet in another workbook. My code only works within the same workbook right now.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub buttonDelete_Click()
'When the Delete button is clicked, the following function is ran to copy the row from Current Services, move it to Cancelled Services
'and then delete the row from Current Services.

Dim wkBk1 As Workbook
Dim wkBk2 As Workbook
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim K As Long
Dim count As Long

On Error Resume Next

Set wkBk1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\testMacro.xlsm")
Set wkBk2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\testMacro2.xlsm")

If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "File Does Not Exist"
End If

I = wkBk1.Worksheets("Current Customers").UsedRange.Rows.count
J = Worksheets("Cancelled Services").UsedRange.Rows.count
count = 0
If J = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Cancelled Services").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Current Customers").Range("A1:A" & I)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For K = 1 To xRg.count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = Me.fName.Value Then
        count = count + 1
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Cancelled Services").Range("A" & J + 1)
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = Me.fName.Value Then
            K = K - 1
        End If
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox count & " rows moved"
End Sub
```

EDIT : OK, here is one more wrinkle. What if I wanted to search through four or five different workbooks, and move all of the rows where the conditions are met into one worksheet called 'Cancelled Services' that will be a worksheet in one of the aforementioned workbooks.

Comment: Have you tried defining a Range, something like 'xRg2' in 'wkBk2' and then copy from xRg to xRg2.
Also to check if the name typed in textbox exists, use Range.Find https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question about checking if a sheet exist in a workbook, you can use a Function like this:

```
Public Function U_W_DoesWorksheetExist(ByVal sheetname As String, aWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    U_W_DoesWorksheetExist = (Not aWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname) Is Nothing)
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Now, when you reference the destination, you are saying just Worksheets("Cancelled Services") and the Macro will assume the ActiveWorkook as the main workbook where to copy the Sheet. You need to reference the Workbook where the sheet you are pasting is located. See if the code below works for you and take a look at the comments I added on it:

```
Private Sub buttonDelete_Click()
'When the Delete button is clicked, the following function is ran to copy the row from Current Services, move it to Cancelled Services
'and then delete the row from Current Services.

    Dim wkBk1 As Workbook
    Dim wkBk2 As Workbook
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim arrFromWorkbookPath(1 To 4) As String
    Dim c As Long



    ' If you need more than 4 rearrange the Array to as many as you need.
    arrFromWorkbookPath(1) = "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\FromWB1.xlsm"
    arrFromWorkbookPath(4) = "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\FromWB2.xlsm"
    arrFromWorkbookPath(3) = "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\FromWB3.xlsm"
    arrFromWorkbookPath(4) = "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\FromWB4.xlsm"

    ' The Workbook were you will be pasting the sheets.
    Set wkBk2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\testMacro2.xlsm")

    For c = LBound(arrFromWorkbookPath) To UBound(arrFromWorkbookPath)

        On Error Resume Next

        ' Open the Workbook from where the sheet will be copied from.
        Set wkBk1 = Workbooks.Open(arrFromWorkbookPath(c))

        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            MsgBox "File Does Not Exist"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' USE PROCEDURE LIKE THIS TO CHECK "Current Customers" in wkBk1 and Cancelled Services in wkBk2.
        If U_W_DoesWorksheetExist("Current Customers", wkBk1) And U_W_DoesWorksheetExist("Cancelled Services", wkBk1) Then

            i = wkBk1.Worksheets("Current Customers").UsedRange.Rows.count
            J = wkBk2.Worksheets("Cancelled Services").UsedRange.Rows.count
            count = 0

            If J = 1 Then
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wkBk2.Worksheets("Cancelled Services").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
            End If

            Set xRg = wkBk1.Worksheets("Current Customers").Range("A1:A" & i)
            On Error Resume Next
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            For K = 1 To xRg.count
                If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = Me.fName.Value Then
                    count = count + 1

                    ' Here you need to specify the workbook, not just the sheet wkBk2.Worksheets("Cancelled Services").
                    xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wkBk2.Worksheets("Cancelled Services").Range("A" & J + 1)
                    xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
                    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = Me.fName.Value Then
                        K = K - 1
                    End If
                    J = J + 1
                End If
            Next

            wkBk1.Close False
        Else

            ' Display error if the sheet doesn't exist.
            MsgBox "Sheets Current Customers or Cancelled Services don't exists."
        End If

    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: EDIT : OK, here is one more wrinkle. What if I wanted to search through four or five different workbooks, and move all of the rows where the conditions are met into one worksheet called 'Cancelled Services' that will be a worksheet in one of the aforementioned workbooks.

Comment: Then you need to loop through every workbook in the Application.Workbooks:

Comment: For Each sh In Application.Workbooks
    
    Next sh

Comment: Once you have the Workbooks, you can use the procedure U_W_DoesWorksheetExist I gave you and check if the sheet exists and use the procedure to paste the rows.

Comment: Don't you need to set the specific workbook you are searching through as the Active workbook? So loop through, set the workbook you want as the active workbook, search for the matching criteria, then paste it to the sheet I want? I apologize, and appreciate your help at the same time. I've done a lot of Java and C# programming, VBA is somewhat new to me.

Comment: You will need to open all the worbooks you will be working with if you want to take this approach. 

What you can also do, it's to have a list of workbooks path in an array and loop through this list and open every workbook using the path, and if it has the worksheet you want, proceed.

Comment: So, an array including the workbooks I want to search, if the sheet exists, then proceed with the above code. So, essentially, if there are four workbooks with one worksheet in each, it will traverse the above code four times, yes?

Comment: Yes, pretty much!

Comment: Care to provide a sample in regards to the above code?

Comment: Try updated code and don't forget to point and close if the answer help. This post has been opened for more than 2 weeks.

Comment: When I try to execute, Excel crashes, VBA Editor crashes, no errors are displayed.

Comment: EDIT : The code tells me 4 times that worksheets "Current Customers" and "Cancelled Services" don't exist. All four workbooks have the sheets "Current Customers" and "Cancelled Services" so this has to be an error in the code. It then does not output anything into the specified file, it creates a new workbook, and puts "NewWKBKValue" in cell A1. No rows are moved.

Comment: Mr. Martinez, have I lost you? We are very close to a solution, but I haven't heard back since my last attempt at editing the code back on March 12.

Comment: Hey @nat0rade there was only one problem. When I was checking for the Sheets, the second sheet was being checked in wkBk2 instead of wkBk1. I updated that section. Please test and let me know.

Comment: Just something I picked up on. When setting the array at the top, you refer to the second iteration in the array as '4' instead of '2'. 
See below :

    `arrFromWorkbookPath(4) = "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\FromWB2.xlsm"

Should be : 

   'arrFromWorkbookPath(2) = "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\FromWB2.xlsm"`

If I am not mistaken?

Comment: Copied the code, still does not work.

It still opens a new workbook, not using the one specified in the code where to paste the sheets, and in the first cell of that workbook, it just displays "NewWKBKValue". That's it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a LOT of strange things  going on in your code, so I've tried to clean it up a bit and left some comments as to why you shouldn't have some things in there. I've addressed the first part of your question, but in order to move rows between workbooks you need to decide what data you're looking to move and where, especially by fully qualifying your ranges using `Workbook`, or in your case, `wkBk1` and `wkBk2`

```
Private Sub buttonDelete_Click()
'When the Delete button is clicked, the following function is ran to copy the row from Current Services, move it to Cancelled Services
'and then delete the row from Current Services.

Dim wkBk1 As Workbook, wkBk2 As Workbook
Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, count As Long
Dim MyName As String

'Assign our name value here
MyName = Me.fName.Value

'Let's use an error handler instead - this way our Err.Number will actually be triggered
On Error GoTo Handler
Set wkBk1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\testMacro.xlsm")
Set wkBk2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\testMacro2.xlsm")
On Error GoTo 0

I = wkBk1.Worksheets("Current Customers").UsedRange.Rows.count
J = Worksheets("Cancelled Services").UsedRange.Rows.count 'Need to add either wkBk1 or wkBk2 to the front of this

'We don't really NEED this, as count is initialized as 0 anyways
'count = 0

If J = 1 Then
    'What is the purpose of this? Can it ever even return true if J = 1?
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Cancelled Services").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
End If

Set xRg = Worksheets("Current Customers").Range("A1:A" & I) 'Need to add either wkBk1 or wkBk2 to the front of this

'Here we check the range for the name. If it's not there, we throw a messsage box and exit the sub
If Not WorksheetFunction.CountIf(xRg, MyName) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Name doesn't exist in the range"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Got rid of On Error Resume Next, we don't need it and it's sloppy coding
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'This whole snippet needs to be changed
'Also since you're deleting rows, you need to step BACKWARDS through this loop
For K = 1 To xRg.count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = MyName Then
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Cancelled Services").Range("A" & J + 1)
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete

            'Why do we have this? We already know this is true?
            'If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = MyName Then
                K = K - 1
            'End If
        'Move count to AFTER we've actually moved the row, with On Error Resume Next your count could've gone up without a row being moved...
        count = count + 1
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox count & " rows moved"

Handler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "File Does Not Exist"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much. If fName matches a value in column A of "Current Services" in wkBk1 I want to move the entire row to a sheet called 'Cancelled Services' in wkBk2. The sheets and workbooks will already be created, the code will not need to create them.

Comment: @nat0rade No problem - I don't typically recommend this but at this point I think you should take the tips I've given here and restructure/rewrite your code completely. I'd get rid of `xRg` completely and just fully qualify your ranges each time using `Workbook` and `Worksheets`. I'd also recommend using another way of finding the lastrow value instead of using `UsedRange`.

Comment: @nat0rade Either that or use one of the suggestions below

Answer (score 0):

This code uses `FIND` rather than looking at each row.  It creates a range of all found rows as it goes and then copies the whole lot over in one hit before deleting the original values. Before ending it tells you how many it found.

This assumes that you have a textbox called `fname` and button called `buttonDelete` on a Userform.

```
Private Sub buttonDelete_Click()

    Dim wrkBk1 As Workbook
    Dim wrkBk2 As Workbook
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim wrkSht1 As Worksheet
    Dim wrkSht2 As Worksheet
    Dim rLastCell_Cur As Range
    Dim rLastCell_Can As Range
    Dim sNameToSearch As String
    Dim rSearchRange As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim lFoundCount As Long
    Dim rFoundUnion As Range

    sPath = "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\"

    If Not (FileExists(sPath & "testMacro.xlsm") And FileExists(sPath & "testMacro2.xlsm")) Then
        'One of the files doesn't exist so display message and exit.
        MsgBox "One of the files does not exist.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
    Else
        Set wrkBk1 = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "testMacro.xlsm")
        Set wrkBk2 = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "testMacro2.xlsm")

        If Not (WorkSheetExists("Current Customers", wrkBk1) And _
                WorkSheetExists("Cancelled Services", wrkBk2)) Then
            'One of the sheets doesn't exist so display message and exit.
            MsgBox "One of the required sheets doesn't exist.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        Else
            'Find the limits of the two sheets.
            Set wrkSht1 = wrkBk1.Worksheets("Current Customers")
            Set rLastCell_Cur = LastCell(wrkSht1)
            Set wrkSht2 = wrkBk2.Worksheets("Cancelled Services")
            Set rLastCell_Can = LastCell(wrkSht2).Offset(1) 'We want the cell below the last cell here.

            'Grab what we're searching for and where we're searching for it.
            sNameToSearch = Me.fName
            With wrkSht1
                Set rSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rLastCell_Cur.Row, 1))
            End With

            With rSearchRange
                'Perform first search.
                Set rFound = .Find(What:=sNameToSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

                'If something was found then we're good to go.
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
                    Do

                        lFoundCount = lFoundCount + 1

                        'Create a union of ranges to copy over.
                        If rFoundUnion Is Nothing Then
                            Set rFoundUnion = rFound.EntireRow
                        Else
                            Set rFoundUnion = Union(rFoundUnion, rFound.EntireRow)
                        End If

                        'Look for the next item.
                        Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)

                    Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress

                    'All instances have been found so copy it all over and then delete the original.
                    rFoundUnion.Copy wrkSht2.Cells(rLastCell_Can.Row, 1)
                    rFoundUnion.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                End If

                MsgBox "Found " & lFoundCount & " occurrences of " & sNameToSearch, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

            End With

        End If
    End If

End Sub

Public Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = Dir(FilePath) <> ""
End Function

Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional WrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If WrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set WrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = WrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet, Optional Col As Long = 0) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        If Col = 0 Then
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        Else
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Columns(Col).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        End If

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

This update to the `buttonDelete_Click()` procedure will open all Excel files within a specific folder and copy the found name to another file that isn't in that folder.

```
Private Sub buttonDelete_Click()

    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim wrkBk1 As Workbook
    Dim wrkBk2 As Workbook
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim wrkSht1 As Worksheet
    Dim wrkSht2 As Worksheet
    Dim rLastCell_Cur As Range
    Dim rLastCell_Can As Range
    Dim sNameToSearch As String
    Dim rSearchRange As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim lFoundCount As Long
    Dim rFoundUnion As Range

    sPath = "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Sandbox\"

    'Put the full path of each Excel file in to a collection.
    'These contain the "Current Customers" sheet.
    Set colFiles = New Collection
    sTemp = Dir$(sPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
        colFiles.Add sPath & sTemp
        sTemp = Dir$
    Loop

    If Not (FileExists("C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Cancelled.xlsx")) Then
        'Cancelled Services book doesn't exist.
        MsgBox "Cancelled Services doesn't exist.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
    Else
        'Open Cancelled Services before working through the collection of Current Customers.
        Set wrkBk2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Cancelled.xlsx")
        Set wrkSht2 = wrkBk2.Worksheets("Cancelled Services")

        For Each vFile In colFiles
            Set wrkBk1 = Workbooks.Open(vFile)

            'The file will only be processed if it contains "Current Customers" sheet.
            If WorkSheetExists("Current Customers", wrkBk1) Then
                Set wrkSht1 = wrkBk1.Worksheets("Current Customers")
                Set rLastCell_Can = LastCell(wrkSht2).Offset(1)
                Set rLastCell_Cur = LastCell(wrkSht1)

                'Grab what we're searching for and where we're searching for it.
                sNameToSearch = Me.fName
                With wrkSht1
                    Set rSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rLastCell_Cur.Row, 1))
                End With

                With rSearchRange
                    'Perform first search.
                    Set rFound = .Find(What:=sNameToSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

                    'If something was found then we're good to go.
                    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                        sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
                        Do

                            lFoundCount = lFoundCount + 1

                            'Create a union of ranges to copy over.
                            If rFoundUnion Is Nothing Then
                                Set rFoundUnion = rFound.EntireRow
                            Else
                                Set rFoundUnion = Union(rFoundUnion, rFound.EntireRow)
                            End If

                            'Look for the next item.
                            Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)

                        Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress

                        'All instances have been found so copy it all over and then delete the original.
                        rFoundUnion.Copy wrkSht2.Cells(rLastCell_Can.Row, 1)
                        rFoundUnion.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If

                End With

            End If

            Set rFound = Nothing
            Set rFoundUnion = Nothing
            sFirstAddress = ""

            wrkBk1.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Next vFile

        MsgBox "Found " & lFoundCount & " occurrences of " & sNameToSearch, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: EDIT : OK, here is one more wrinkle. What if I wanted to search through four or five different workbooks, and move all of the rows where the conditions are met into one worksheet called 'Cancelled Services' that will be a worksheet in one of the aforementioned workbooks.

Comment: Four or five books that are all in the same folder, or choose each book separately? `Cancelled Services` is randomly in one of those books or a specific one?

Comment: The workbooks are not all in the same folder. They are in various folders on our Network Share on our local file server.

Comment: How do you select which workbooks to extract data from?  Do you individually select each file, is there a list of files on one of the worksheets, or some other method?

Comment: I know which four workbooks I want to search. I will specify them in the code, and their filepath, but I am unsure of how to tell the code which workbook I have active, and am looking through. Basically, the code should search four workbooks that I specify, tell me if any of the values in column A match what was typed in the 'Input Name' text field, and if they do, move those specific rows to a sheet in another specified workbook. Does this help with the scope of what the code should do?